# Python pip compatibility

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

If I use two Python versions with path variables set and later use 
pip install (package name)..which pip will get activated.
Both versions come with inbuilt pip .

Iam a Python beginner..please help

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Python come with a [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).  It is already in the path and allows choosing which Python to run.  Remove `python` from your path and use the launcher instead:

```
py -3 -m pip <options>   # Run latest Python 3 found on the system with its pip.
py -2 -m pip <options>   # Use latest Python 2 instead.
```

The launcher has more options.  See the link provided.  You may need to reinstall a recent Python 3 to make sure the launcher is installed and it is registered for Python extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pip` then Python-2.7's pip is triggered, for Python-3.x you have to use `pip3`.

i.e for Python-2.7

```
pip install <package_name>
```

for Python-3.x

```
pip3 install <package_name>
```